Pandas Dataframe Take Sum and Get the Newest Date in PYTHON
Here is the meta data related with  my big dataset.



Organization
Total_Founding
announced_on




O4
50
2015-03-26


O2
70
2016-10-10


O1
20
2016-10-14


O4
80
2015-05-26


O2
30
2016-12-10


O2
60
2017-01-10



First of all I want to take the sum of total founding with respect to each organizations and rewrite the summation to the "Total Founding" column.



Organization
Total Founding
announced_on




O4
130
2015-03-26


O2
160
2016-10-10


O1
20
2016-10-14


O4
130
2015-05-26


O2
160
2016-12-10


O2
160
2017-01-10



Second one that I want to reach is getting the newest date of "announced_on" column for each organizations.



Organization
Total Founding
announced_on




O1
20
2016-10-14


O4
130
2015-05-26


O2
160
2017-01-10



Could you please help me?

Can you provide your attempts as [mre]s? Where are you getting stuck?

I cannot write the correct codes. I tried to use groupby method but couldn't find the latest table.

u need to groupby by Organization and aggregate by other 2 columns using sum and max funcs

You can get the second result dataframe in one step with groupby and agg with sum and 'last'.
But if you need the first as an intermediate:
df_1 = df.copy().set_index("Organization")
df_1["Total Founding"] = df_1.groupby("Organization")["Total_Founding"].sum()
df_1 = df_1.reset_index()

  Organization  Total_Founding announced_on  Total Founding
0           O4              50   2015-03-26             130
1           O2              70   2016-10-10             160
2           O1              20   2016-10-14              20
3           O4              80   2015-05-26             130
4           O2              30   2016-12-10             160
5           O2              60   2017-01-10             160

To get the second:
df = (
    df.sort_values("announced_on")
    .groupby("Organization", as_index=False)
    .agg({"Total_Founding": sum, "announced_on": "last"})
    .rename(columns={"Total_Founding": "Total Founding"})
)

  Organization  Total Founding announced_on
0           O1              20   2016-10-14
1           O2             160   2017-01-10
2           O4             130   2015-05-26


You can do this with a one-liner and the column renaming if that is what you intended:
df.groupby('Organization', as_index=False).agg(**{'Total Founding':('Total_Founding','sum'), 'announced_on':('announced_on','last')})

Output:
  Organization  Total Founding announced_on
0           O1              20   2016-10-14
1           O2             160   2017-01-10
2           O4             130   2015-05-26

